# Unable to use Date module in Drupal 7

Tags: date, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I had used the date module in Drupal 6 for my custom module.But in Drupal 7, i am getting this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function date_popup_load() in C:\xampp\htdocs\widgetcorp\sites\all\modules\freeway\freeway.admin.inc on line 164
```

This is the form iam using it in is as follows.

```
function create_freeway_project (){
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  $form = array();
  date_popup_load();

  $form['title'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Project Description'),
  '#size' => 60,
  '#maxlength' => 128,
  '#required' => TRUE,
);

  $form['custRef'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Customer Reference'),
  '#size' => 60,
  '#maxlength' => 128,
  '#required' => TRUE,
);

  $form['poRef'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('PO Reference'),
  '#size' => 60,
  '#maxlength' => 128,
  '#required' => TRUE,
);


  $form['splinst'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => t('Special Instructions'),
  '#size' => 60,
  '#maxlength' => 128,
  '#required' => TRUE,
);


  $form['strtdate'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date_popup',
  '#title' => t('Delivery Date'),
  '#size' => 60,
  '#maxlength' => 128,
  '#required' => TRUE,
);


  $form['enddate'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date_popup',
  '#title' => t('End Date'),
  '#size' => 60,
  '#maxlength' => 128,
  '#required' => TRUE,
);


   $form['create_project_btn'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Create Freeway Project',
  );


   return $form;

}
```

Is the Jquery_UI module to be added ? I did not find its mention in the Date module for Drupal 7.
Please let me know if i am missing something.

Thanks
A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do any of the setup yourself in Drupal 7, it's as simple as this:

```
$form['strtdate'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date_popup',
  '#title' => t('Delivery Date'),
  '#size' => 60,
  '#maxlength' => 128,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#date_format' => 'd/m/Y H:i' // With this format you'll get a date popup box AND a time widget. Obviously you can change this to whatever you need.
);
```

The date module will handle adding the required JS.

Have a look at the [`date_popup_element_info()`](http://api.lullabot.com/date_popup_element_info/7) function for a full list of the available options for this element type.

Comment: Thanks Clive i am able to see the date popup